# Jenkins not able to poll Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins on a Tomcat 7.0 in a Windows machine and I'm having some trouble trying to retrieve the content of a Git repository on a Unix machine.

When I input the repository url, I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\path\to\git\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://user@path/to/repo HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I log in with the tomcat user (or mine) and run in a terminal

```
C:\path\to\git\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://user@path/to/repo HEAD
```

I get no errors.

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

On the Unix machine I have PasswordAuthentication set to yes and PubkeyAuthentication set to no, since we are using Likewise to connect with our Active Directory accounts.